# Wubi-move-to-partition worked but didn't install the bootloader, what do I do?

Tags: installation, partitioning, wubi

I am on Ubuntu 10.10 and installed it through wubi. But the script exited at copying var/tmp. I do not have the exact error message but it said that some files were deleted before they could be transfered. I was confused so I restarted the computer. Now the computer still books into wubi but I cannot reuse the script as it says that the partition I am moving to is in use.

```
sudo ./wubi-move-to-partition /dev/sda7 /dev/sda6
Sanity checks...
Volume /dev/sda7 is in use. Aborting
```

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this script on 10.10. It doesn't work anymore. Look at the [wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F) for a link to the latest migration script.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible reason

Looks like it stopped after migrate_files ( function in that script ) and now it refuses to do it again because it checks if partition is formatted - you can see part of script that checks it here

```
    if mount -t auto "$dev" $target 2> /dev/null; then
    if [ $(ls -1 $target | wc -l) -gt 1 ] || \
    [ "$(ls -1 $target)" != "lost+found" ]; then    
        echo "Volume $dev is in use. Aborting"
        umount $target || true        
        exit 1
    fi
    umount $target
fi
```

if it find folder lost+found, which is usually on ext filesystems, it prints out Volume is in use and exits.

### and possible solution

So, if you still can boot into wubi, delete filesystem from that partition by running gparted, select partition /dev/sda7, delete it. Then make new unformatted partition on same spot ( right click on unallocated, new, choose filesystem unformatted ). And run script again

### possible solution if script will stop again

if it will stop again after copying files from /var/tmp, check what is there and you can exclude it from copying by adding --exclude /var/tmp/folder_that_dont_like_to_be_copied 
parameter to this part of script after --exclude=/sys/*

```
migrate_files(){
    echo "Migrating files..."
    rsync -av --exclude=/host --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/home/*/.gvfs --exclude=/media/*/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* / $target
}
```